How do I fix this bug in my toy `Vector` class?
I wrote my own toy Vector class to better understand all allocations/deallocations going on, in an effort to appreciate why move semantics is more efficient. While my program builds on MSVS 2022, it fails to build only on Compiler Explorer; I tried both gcc and msvc compilers.
I'd like to ask for some help to learn why my code doesn't even build. The return code 139 isn't very helpful.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <initializer_list>


template <typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    int capacity_;
    int size_;
    T* ptr_;

public:
    Vector<T>() :capacity_{ 0 }, size_{ 0 }, ptr_{ nullptr } {}
    Vector<T>(int size) : capacity_{ size }, ptr_{ new T[size] }, size_{ size } {}
    Vector<T>(int size, T data) : Vector<T>(size) {
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i)
            ptr_[i] = data;
    }

    Vector<T>(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
        clear();
        for (const T& elem : list)
            push_back(elem);
    }

    //Destructor
    ~Vector<T>()
    {
        clear();
    }

    //Copy constructor
    Vector<T>(const Vector<T>& v)
    {
        if (this == &v)
            return;

        capacity_ = v.capacity_;
        size_ = v.size_;
        ptr_ = new T[v.size_];

        for (int i{ 0 }; i < v.size_; ++i)
            ptr_[i] = v.ptr_[i];
    }

    //Copy assignment operator
    Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector<T>& v)
    {
        if (this != &v)
        {
            delete[] ptr_;
            ptr_ = nullptr;

            capacity_ = v.capacity_;
            size_ = v.size_;
            ptr_ = new T[capacity_];

            for (int i{ 0 }; i < v.size_; ++i)
                ptr_[i] = v.ptr_[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T operator[](int i)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < size_)
            return ptr_[i];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds.");
    }

    T operator[](int i) const
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < size_)
            return ptr_[i];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds.");
    }

    void reserve(int size)
    {
        if (size_ < capacity_) return;

        if (ptr_ == nullptr)
        {
            size_ = 0;
            capacity_ = 0;
        }

        T* bufferNew = new T[size];
        unsigned int l_size = std::min(capacity_, size);
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < l_size; ++i)
        {
            bufferNew[i] = ptr_[i];
        }

        if (ptr_ != nullptr)
            delete[] ptr_;

        ptr_ = bufferNew;
        capacity_ = size;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        if (ptr_ != nullptr)
            delete[] ptr_;
        ptr_ = nullptr;
        size_ = 0;
        capacity_ = 0;
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return size_;
    }

    int capacity()
    {
        return capacity_;
    }

    void push_back(const T& elem)
    {
        if (size_ >= capacity_) {
            reserve(capacity_ == 0 ? 1 : capacity_ * 2); // Double the capacity
        }

        ptr_[size_++] = elem;
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        --size_;
    }

    T front()
    {
        if (size_ > 0)
            return ptr_[0];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds.");
    }

    T back()
    {
        if (size_ > 0)
            return ptr_[size_ - 1];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds.");
    }

    T* getRawPointer()
    {
        return ptr_;
    }
};

template <typename T>
Vector<T> operator+(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
{
    std::cout << "\nInside operator+";
    if (v1.size() != v2.size())
        throw std::logic_error("Vector lengths must be equal.");
    Vector<T> result;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < v1.size(); ++i)
        result.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);

    return result;
}

Vector<Vector<double>> createAndInsert()
{
    Vector<Vector<double>> pts;
    pts.reserve(3);
    Vector<double> x{ 1.0, 1.0 };
    std::cout << "\nCheckpoint #1";
    std::cout << "\npts->ptr_ = "<<pts.getRawPointer();
    std::cout << "\nx->ptr_ = "<<x.getRawPointer();
    pts.push_back(x);
    std::cout << "\nCheckpoint #2";
    std::cout << "\npts[0]->ptr_ = " << pts[0].getRawPointer();
    pts.push_back(x + x);
    std::cout << "\npts[1]->ptr_ = " << pts[1].getRawPointer();
    pts.push_back(x);
    std::cout << "\nCheckpoint #3";
    std::cout << "\npts[2]->ptr_ = " << pts[2].getRawPointer();
    return pts;
}

int main()
{
    Vector<Vector<double>> result = createAndInsert();
    return 0;
}


I actually recommend you start over, with an empty main function and nothing more. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When it builds then test. When the tests pass, add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. If (when) there's a problem, it's much easier to isolate it into a [mre] and find a solution.

Your Godbolt (compiler explorer) link does not show any compilation error.

The ptr_ member is not always initialized for all the constructors. You could try to assign a defaut value while defining it (ie. T* ptr_ = nullptr;)

Lot of warnings, but no compilation errors Demo

Is it really an issue during the compilation or is it a crash while running the program ? Actually, it appears to crash because of an uninitialized member ptr_ when calling the constructor with initializer list (with code 134 for me with gcc).

Vector(std::initializer_list<T> list) doesn't inialize ptr_ (spot by compiler warnings BTW).

@Jarod42, why do I see the same addresses in pts[0].getRawPointer(), pts[1].getRawPointer() and pts[2].getRawPointer()? I have implemented copy semantics correctly.
https://godbolt.org/z/sasr8WffP

Your operator [] return copy instead of reference, and those temporaries are destroyed just after full expression. It happens that those reference use same pointer.

Initializing all member variables is usually a good idea, either inline or in constructor initializer list. Copy construct and assingment have a lot of common code, consider refactoring.

T* ptr_; is an owning raw pointer.  That's bad.  Use std::unique_ptr<T[]> ptr_; instead.

@Eljay, I agree with you. The purpose of the exercise was to understand performance penalties (multiple wasteful allocations and deallocations) when using value semantics and the motivation for move semantics.

Since your operator[] returns a temporary copy, consider adding a auto ref(int i) const -> T const& method to return a reference, and use that instead in your createAndInsert function.

"The return code 139 isn't very helpful." -- True, and it's even less helpful when you present this tidbit without context. You've managed to ask how to fix "this bug" in your toy Vector class without stating what "this bug" is. (Well, there is "fails to build only on Compiler Explorer", which is better than nothing, but still inadequate, or possibly inaccurate. A question about a build failure must include the compiler's error message.)
